# EF not inserting into database after adding new Properties to Registration form

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I added two new fields to `RegisterViewModel` class in asp.net MVC default code. Validation works but, values for the newly added fields are not inserted into the database, other fields are inserted. No error is returned from the page.

I'm guessing I need to do some things inside `AccountController` class, somewhere around here:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

Not sure exactly how.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
               //await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
                 string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                 var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                 await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                TempData["Email"] = user.Email;
                return RedirectToAction("Confirm", "Account");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Could you share code.

Comment: Are you certain that `SaveChanges` is being called on your context object?

Comment: I do not have `SaveChanges` in `AccountController`

Comment: @Dai Only fields I just added are not inserted into the database. Other fields are inserted.

Comment: @hello May be because you have added in viewmodel not in entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to add new field to database you need to add to modify model `ApplicationUser` not viewModel `RegisterViewModel`.
So in your question you need to add new field to `RegisterViewModel` model but actually you need to update the `ApplicationUser` class because  `RegisterViewModel` used for UI only. For example, to add new field `PersonId` you need to modify your `ApplicationUser` model and migrate your database

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
    public string PersonId { get; set; }
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
```

and add `public string PersonId { get; set; }` to your ViewModel `RegisterViewModel` with any Validation you need then in save code convert ViewModel to Model

```
var user = new ApplicationUser 
            {
                UserName = model.Email,
                Email = model.Email,
                PersonId = model.PersonId,
            };
result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't assign the  new properties in the `ApplicationUser` instance, lets say you added a `PhoneNumber' property inside the model class, then you have to copy its value to the user as below

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email,PhoneNumber=model.PhoneNumber };
```